# rails serialized association instead of has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, serialization

Can I serialize an association? I mean, I have a `Question` model that `has_many Interests :through => :interests_questions`. Questions and interests tables are huge and I don't want to make their size increase. So, is there a way to make `interests_questions` table with columns `question_id` and `interests_ids` where interest_ids receive a serialized Hash containing all associated interests?

Does activeRecord handle this kind of stuff or is there a Gem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord doesn't do that. Mostly because of the fact that this is not a classical approach for RDBM systems. The problem is that you could really only see all interests for one or more questions and that would immediately involve two queries, because you can't `join` or `includes`. Additionally, you can't run (db) queries that depend on the relationship between questions and interests. For example asking for all interests that have been created less than a week ago and belong to questions 5, 9, 12 could only be done by iterating all interests of those questions in ruby.

You could have a look at Mongoid for MongoDB. It does exactly that. It could even embed all interests entirely within a question.

Comment: I believe that you can still query on serialized data using PostgreSQL's `json` data type and some indexes on it. I'm not sure that that would be a wise approach in this scenario though.